# How to remove undeletable login item

Tags: macos, login-items

[image]

I have a login item that I can't delete! It's a random Garageband audio file that I never put there myself. It opens in Quicktime every time I boot my Mac. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is set for all users it should be in the

```
/System/Library/StartupItems
```

or in the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

Correction thanks to @maximus that would be in the `/Library/LaunchAgents`

Copy one of the above and paste it in the Finders "Go to Folder"

Alternatively hover the mouse pointer over it (while it is highlighted) and there should be a pop up with the location of that file.

Comment: I think you mean /Library/LaunchAgents,

Comment: Spotlighting in both those folders for "Steinway" returns no results. If I right click on the login item and choose "Show in Finder", it takes me to the file's original location in Application Support/Garageband/.

Comment: For the future - all I needed to do was click the padlock button under the login items list, then after entering my password I could delete the login item. Doh.

Comment: one keeps learning... hopefully :)

Comment: ``~/Library/LaunchAgents`` i.e. ``/Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents`` is the location :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Apple Developer Resource](https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/deployment/depdca572563/web), one may list background tasks, including **login items**  via command:

```
sfltool dumpbtm
```

And reset the background task database (backgrounditems.btm) via:

```
sfltool resetbtm
```

For my personal experience (MBP Pro 16 2019 + Sonoma), the database will be rebuilt automatically once you restart the applications you want to start at login.

Answer (score 0):

**For Sierra.** 
Search out and destroy a file called ***backgrounditems.btm*** then reboot. The login panel should be cleared out.
Only this method helped me...

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8086931?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path of the `backgrounditems.btm` file is here:
`/Users/$your_user/Library/Application Support/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagementagent/backgrounditems.btm`

found via typing this into Terminal:

```
sudo find / -name backgrounditems.btm -not -path '*TimeMachine*'.
```

You will see this at the bottom. Copy it, then at the top look for go and run this in go and all you have to do now is just delete that file and restart and your done. Good luck.

`/Users/$your_user/Library/Application Support/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagementagent/backgrounditems.btm`
 
I have just deleted the file; will post back here after a reboot.

Answer (score -1):

The file `/Users/your_username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` should contain the link to this file. Using **Get Info**, check to see that your user account has Read & Write Privilege.

I noticed that the minus sign used for deleting items from this list is greyed out. Can you remove other items from this list?